# Site map for organization name contain reference to entity but that entity name was not found in metadata cache

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

`Site map for organization name contain reference to entity but that entity name was not found in metadata cache`

I got this error in an event viewer on the application server.

Tried to make an unmanaged solution with Site map of the organization (checked specially in database of which the id was in the error description)

The issue is that there isn't any entity with the same name as in the error message.

Does anyone another way to fix that error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the entity being deleted and the sitemap not being updated as Jors said, but if you've already checked the sitemap for the entity, check that you only have a single tenancy. The error could be occurring in a different crm tenancy

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this issue is when customizations are moved between environments and entities get deleted in this process, but the sitemap still has references to them.

You can follow the steps on [this](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/04/04/crm-sitemap-references-an-entity-not-found-in-the-metadata-cache/) link to fix your problem.

Comment: Did you downvote because an answer was offered that you have already attempted? That's not really why you down vote. +1.